# How do I draw someones attention to a document that is already shared with them?

Tags: office-365

We have SharePoint in Office365 and store some shared documents there. All members of my team have access.

When I create a document there, I want to point certain colleagues to it so that the know it is there and to edit it.

These documents are already shared with them but all sharing and get link options seem to refer to creating new sharing methods. How do I simply point someone at a document that is already shared with them?

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe them to the list and every time an new item is created the get an email immediately or daily.

Comment: Thanks. That could work in some instances but in most I definitely want to highlight a specific file. When I share or get a link, am I really creating a new share? Or is sharepoint smart enough to use the existing one?

Comment: I know you can set up alerts on folders for a group of people. If you want people notified on individual items, they can subscribe to it so they are notified of changes. Another option is to create a simple workflow on the list. It could fire off emails when created and/or modified to different people based on some form choices, or just send to everyone.